# is UID in firebase automatically created/read for each user?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, authentication, uid

I'm sorry if my question is basic question...

is UID in firebase automatically created when we implement `.setUid()` at the first user sign-up account? and if we are login to that user account and implement `.getUid()`, can we retrieve the same UID?

I use Android Studio and Kotlin as programming language

Comment: When a user signs in, they are issued a User ID that is available on the ID token used for that session. Are you talking about using `getUid` and `setUid` on an data model class for use with Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot it. I try to using Realtime Database on my case

Comment: Please edit the programming language and platform into the question as well.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information samthecodingman asked for, and please also responded with @.

Comment: Thanks for correction sir, i'm sorry if i made a lot of mistakes @samthecodingman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter how you implement authentication on your app, firebase will automatically set a uid for each account created. If you go to the auth section of your firebase console and manually add an account, you will see on the right hand side a uid generated for that account.

To reference this uid within your code the uid does not need to be stored in any database solution for the uid is attatched to the account within FirebaseAuth..

To pull the uid for reference once the user has signed in, first you need to set the auth global variable..

private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

Then anywhere within the scope of your functions you can set your uid reference variable like this..

val myUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.uid;

Comment: Thank you very much sir, this is so clear. Now i understand how the uid works